# Ruby block/anonymous function placeholder parameter

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for the following syntax in Ruby`[1,2,3].map {|n| f(n)}` -> `[1,2,3].map(f(_))`. In Scala it's called a placeholder parameter.

Would it be possible to implement in ruby itself? Are there plans of adding some form of this syntax to the ruby language?

Comment: Sounds like Perl's `$_`.

Comment: May I ask what would be wrong with the existing since the stone age `[1,2,3].map(&f)`?

Comment: Yep, that works great too in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't yet, but it may happen soon. The most likely syntax (as of 2019-08-29) would be

```
[1, 2, 3].map { f(_1) }
```

You can read the feature request [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4475); the follow-up discussion [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15723) is a more recent take on it.

Comment: For the particular case of the only parameter, there is `[1,2,3].map(&f)`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: Huh, that actually works. Thanks.

Comment: This is no longer just a proposal in 2023 btw, it has now been a language feature for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looks like the feature itself is called numbered parameters and is already available in ruby-2.7.0-dev, checked it just now.

The example from the question can be written as `[1,2,3].map { f(@1) }`

Comment: Yes, but it will likely not cross from dev to stable in that form, as the feature is quite controversial. What I wrote in my answer is the conclusion of the dev meeting, as stated by Matz himself.